# Extracting data from one workbook, depending on the column Names and pasting it in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbook . Book1 and Book2.

I want to copy the Contents of Book1, sheet1 to book2 sheet3.

The data in my sheet1 of  book1 starts from row 22, and i want them to be pasted from row 5 for book2 of sheet3.

I have in few cases, where I want to skip the columns and paste the selected columns.

For eg: from bk1, sht1, I want column A to be pasted in Column B of Bk2, sht3 ; 
Bk1 sht1, Column B pasted in column A of sht3, Column C of Bk1 sht3, in column I of bk2 sht3. Like this.

I tried with a code, where i am looking for column and not the names.

For eg: instead of split(Column A), I would like to have Split("Project Name") and paste them in column B of my sheet.

```
Sub ExtractBU()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

CopyCol = Split("A,B,C,D,E,F,H,I,K,L,M,O,P", ",")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LCell = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
LCC = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
lcr = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set y = ThisWorkbook
    Dim path1, Path2
path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Path2 = path1 & "\Downloads"
Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename:=Path2 & "\Report.xlsx")

For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol)
  Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "22:" & CopyCol(Count) & lcr)
  If Count = 0 Then
    Set CopyRange = temp
  Else
    Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
  End If
Next

CopyRange.Copy
y.Sheets("BU").Paste y.Sheets("BU").Range("A4")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
x.Close
End Sub
```

can anyone tell me how i can do this  ? Any lead would be helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "Column Names"? Is there a row with titles (first one, I guess)?

Comment: Also, 1) you are openening a file (`x`) and closing it without performing any task, 2) when you set CopyRange as a union you are selecting the full range (columns A to P, rows 22 to lcr): it seems odd to use an array and union for that, and 3) you are not using variables LR, LC, LCell and LCC: is there a reason for that?

Comment: @CMArg Column Names, I meant here is the headers. and I am not using them.

Comment: To sum up: you want to copy range("A22:P" & LastRow) of the workbook/worksheet where code resides to row 5 of sheet "BU" of the other workbook (Report.xlsx)?

Comment: I want  to open Report and copy rows (A22:P &lastrow) and copy them in BU from row 5 . The code resides in BU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. **Edited according to comments**.

```
Sub ExtractBU()
    Dim DestinationWB As Workbook
    Dim OriginWB As Workbook
    Dim path1 As String
    Dim FileWithPath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim TheHeader As String
    Dim cell As Range

    Set OriginWB = ThisWorkbook
    path1 = OriginWB.Path
    FileWithPath = path1 & "\Downloads\Report.xlsx"
    Set DestinationWB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FileWithPath)


    LastRow = OriginWB.Worksheets("BU").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = OriginWB.Worksheets("BU").Cells(22, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastCol
        'get the name of the field (names are in row 22)
        TheHeader = OriginWB.Worksheets("BU").Cells(22, i).Value

        With DestinationWB.Worksheets("BU").Range("A4:P4")
            'Find the name of the field (TheHeader) in the destination (in row 4)
            Set cell = .Find(TheHeader, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With

        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            OriginWB.Worksheets("BU").Range(Cells(23, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).Copy Destination:=DestinationWB.Worksheets("BU").Cells(5, cell.Column)
        Else
            'handle the error
        End If
    Next i

    'DestinationWB.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Cmarg, thank you for the code and considering my request.  I think I have mentioned, instead of looking into colunmn A , I would like to look into the headers ."Project name " and then copy.

Comment: "Project name" and others are in the first row?

Comment: in row 22  have column A I have "project name" and in Bk2 of row 5 I have "Project name" So instead looking into column A , I want to look into the header and paste the data

Comment: Things are getting clear, but all those details were not at all clear in your original question. So what you REALLY want to do is 1) read the header of the first column (header is in row 22), 2) find the column with that same header (in row 4) in the other workbook, and then 3) copy and paste the data??

Comment: I will get back to you, If I have any questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151681/discussion-between-jenny-and-cmarg).

Comment: Thank you for your help and I have accepted it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking for, with out all the extra code, once again "keep it simple".

```
Sub test()
Dim lRow As Long

Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Downloads" & "\Report.xlsx"

lRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Range("A22:P" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Report.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A5")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplest code. But in my case i have obstacles like. In Book1 I want a column C to be pasted in Book2 A, which is completely jumbled. That's why I mentioned split with column (A,B,C, etc) also, Now i dont want to look for Column A, instead i want to look for Header and paste them accordingly

Comment: with this code, I could understand that you copy everything from Column A till Column P. But in between I have cases where I need to leave the inbetween columns .and jump to next column.

Comment: Please be more clear when you ask your questions, you are being too broad. Identify exactly what columns you need to copy.

Comment: I have now updated the question .Sorry from my side that I dint mention it properly, Here after I make sure I list out it properly

Comment: In the destination workbook, there will be empty columns?

Comment: @CMArg what this means ? I could not follow

Comment: @CMArg Tried to vote up your answer, will try again when i can sign in.